# Need to display wide table using PrimeNG framework

Tags: primeng, primeng-table

I am designing an attendance dashboard using Angular and PrimeNG UI framework.
There is a use case where admin has to select a period (normally a month long) to show work/absence.

Here is the table example I modified to include the duration
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-widetbl-sa1?

I noticed due to the 'responsive-design', it has to fit everything into a page wide which is very ugly. Is there a way to enable horizontal bar and still compatible with PrimeNG framework? How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add `autoLayout="true"` to your `p-table` tag.

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-widetbl-sa1-mpfehx?file=src/app/app.component.html)

PrimeNG doc:

> If you require cells to scale based on their contents set `autoLayout`
> property to true.